# Using grep and if statement in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script, grep

I want to search a string in a file, and after much searching this website, I ended up using `grep` in and `if` statement. However, things aren't working as I expect them, even though I followed all the instructions I found on other related posts. Here's my code.

```
echo "Enter dicounter number"
read string1
echo "Enter side with LEDs"
read string2

if grep -q "dicounter_$string1_from_$string2" MasterFile.txt; then
   echo "dicounter_$string1_from$string2 already exists in MasterFile."
else
   { (a bunch of stuff to make the transmitter operate) }
fi
```

The primary problem I think is with the way I am reading in my command line arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a script is not working as you expect it to, one of the first things you might want to try is adding `set -x` before the troublesome spot in the code (in this case, before the `grep`), and running the script.  You will then see what the script is *actually* doing, so that you can compare that to what you *expect* it to be doing.

In your case, the problem may be that `_` is a valid character in variable names, so you are attempting to use value of `$string1_from_` rather than `$string1` as you expect.  This is why it is a good practice, even if not using fancy manipulations, to enclose your variable names in curly braces.  For example:

```
if grep -q "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}" MasterFile.txt; then
   echo "dicounter_${string1}_from${string2} already exists in MasterFile."
else
   [..]
```

Comment: A follow up question: After a while, the `MasterFile.txt` will have thousands of entries. Do you recommend a faster/more efficient way of searching for the strings?

Comment: @Ptheguy Using `grep - q` is already very fast, as it will quit as soon as it finds a match. The other thing you may try is to make the pattern more specific. This may possibly be done by anchoring the pattern to the beginning and/or end of the line (I haven't benchmarked to see if this actually makes a difference).

Comment: You can use `grep -ql`, which will stop at the first match rather than proceeding through the rest of the file.

Comment: You can check the grep execution time separately, by commenting the other code and run your script this way: `time your_script.sh`. Or estimate grep only: `time grep -q "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}" MasterFile.txt`.

Comment: A syntax highlighting editor would also be a good tool to spot issues like this, though it might be that they'll just highlight the whole quoted string with one color. shellcheck.net warns about unset variables, though...

Comment: `vim` seems to DTRT:  http://i.imgur.com/4QJwi88.png
Also, you can `set -u` to make referencing an unset or undeclared variable an error condition which will cause the script to terminate.